# Python Pandas return DataFrame where value count is above a set number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, and I want to return the DataFrame only if that Customer Number occurs more than a set number of times.

Here is a sample of the DataFrame:

```
114  2017-04-26      1       7507       34      13
115  2017-04-26      3      77314       41      14
116  2017-04-27      7       4525      190     315
117  2017-04-27      7       5525       67      94
118  2017-04-27      1       6525       43     378
119  2017-04-27      3       7415       38      27
120  2017-04-27      2       7613       47      10
121  2017-04-27      2      77314        9       3
122  2017-04-28      1        227       17       4
123  2017-04-28      8       4525      205     341
124  2017-04-28      1       7415       31      20
125  2017-04-28      2      77314        8       2
```

And here is if that customer occurs more than 5 times, using this code:

```
print(zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts()>5)

7415      True
4525      True
5525      True
77314     True
6525      True
4111      True
227       True
206      False
7507     False
7613     False
4108     False
3046     False
2605     False
4139     False
4119     False
```

Now I expected if I did this:

```
print(zip_data_df[zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts()>5])
```

It would show me the whole DataFrame for customers that occur more than 5 times, but I got a Boolean error. I realize why it gives me an error now: one DataFrame is just telling me if that customer number occurs more than 5 times or not, and the other is showing me every time that customer number occurs. They don't match in length. But how do I get it so the dataframe will only return records where that customer occurs more than 5 times?

I'm sure there is some simple answer I'm overlooking, but I appreciate any help you can get me.

Comment: My thinking is I need to add a column that does a custcount similar to what I believe Abe suggested, so I tried this:

zip_data_df['cust_counts'] = zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts()

But it just gives me a "NaN" for all cust_counts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the issue here is indexing: value_counts() returns a Series indexed on 'Customers,' while zip_data_df seems to be indexed on something else. You can do something like:

```
cust_counts = zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts().rename('cust_counts')

zip_data_df = zip_data_df.merge(cust_counts.to_frame(),
                                left_on='Customers',
                                right_index=True)
```

From there, you can select conditionally from zip_data_df like so:

```
zip_data_df[zip_data_df.cust_counts > 5]
```

Comment: I get this error from that solution:

ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: @Emac ok in the merge, replace the first arg **cust_counts** with **cust_counts.to_frame()**

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and solved it this way.

```
cust_counts = zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts()
cust_list = cust_counts[cust_counts > 5].index.tolist()
zip_data_df = zip_data_df[zip_data_df['Customers'].isin(cust_list)]
```

Comment: Excellent straightforward solution!

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts()[zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts()>5]
```

Comment: The problem is that only returns the customers that occur more than 5 times, but I want to return the whole row (all fields) if that customer has more than 5 occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the job done with a handy little groupby transform here

```
subset_customers_df = zip_data_df[
          zip_data_df.groupby('Customers')
         ['Customers'].transform('size')>5]
```

that works here for Pandas 0.25.3

Answer (score 0):

```
# create the boolean series 
s1 = pd.series(zip_data_df['Customers'].value_counts()) 

 # select rows that are greater than 5
result = [i for i,j in zip(s1.index,s1.value) if j>5]

 # select rows based values in the result list 
zip_data_df[zip_data_df.Customers.isin(result)]
```

This worked for me ,although its lame to write this long code, it is easier understand than oneliners

Answer (score -1):

Haven 't tried but this should work:

```
cust_by_size = zip_data_df.groupBy("Customers").size()
cust_index_gt_5 = cust_by_size.index[cust_by_size > 5]
zip_data_cust_index_gt_5 = zip_data_df[zip_data_df["Customers"].isin(cust_index_gt_5)]
```